# how to aggregate data by age for rows spanning across different timeline

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge table with over 10,00,000 rows and growing. The data looks like something like this

```
id     topic_id      publish_date            hits
-------------------------------------------------
1        1          2014-01-01               20
2        1          2014-01-01               10
3        1          2014-01-03               10
4        2          2014-01-10               50
5        2          2014-01-15              100
...
...
```

I have another table with topics with id, name, start_date, end_date.

I need to retrieve hit data from the table daywise hits for each topic. This will enable me to compare their performance on each day

eg:

```
Topic ->            1            2
day
1                   x            y
2                   y            a
3                   z            b
```

so on.

I hope I made a proper explanation.

What I am trying to do is:

```
SELECT report.topic_id, topic.start_date,
 SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(report.hits , en.start_date) = 0, hit,0)) as d0
,SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(report.hits , en.start_date) = 1, hit,0)) as d1
,SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(report.hits , en.start_date) = 2, hit,0)) as d2
,SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(report.hits , en.start_date) = 3, hit,0)) as d3
,SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(report.hits , en.start_date) = 4, hit,0)) as d4
,SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(report.hits , en.start_date) = 5, hit,0)) as d5
from report left join topic en on report.topic_id = en.id
where topic_id in (1,2,4)
group by topic_id
```

It takes 10-12 seconds to generate the result data. I am using PHP & MySQL. I willing to do tradeoff taking off the db load with script calculation, caching results.

Is there a better way to do this? I am looking at faster way to retrieve results.

Comment: Are you getting the results you were expecting?

Comment: Yea. I am getting the results I want. But its very slow. I am wondering if there's a  better method

Comment: Do you have an index on report.topic_id and on topic.id ?

Comment: Do `size` and `hits` are the same field? What is `en`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code.
1. size = hits
2. topic = en